# Removing a list of elements from a list of elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a list of elements. I want to remove three of these elements at the same time.

I tried doing a list comprehension type of a thing. `log_r.columns` is an array of the column names from a `pd.DataFrame()`. This is what it looks like:

`array(['MBI10', 'SAX', 'PX', 'CAC40', 'CRBEX', 'SOFIX', 'DAX', 'SBITOP',
       'BELEX15', 'UAX', 'SASX10', 'AEX', 'BET', 'BUX'], dtype=object)`.

I want to remove `'AEX'`, `'DAX'` and `'CAC40'`

```py
emerging_names = log_r.columns.values[log_r.columns.values != ['AEX','DAX','CAC40']]


FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with inverting mask by `~`:

```
emerging_names = log_r.columns.values[~log_r.columns.isin(['AEX','DAX','CAC40'])]
```

Or use list comprehension with filtering:

```
emerging_names = [x for x in log_r.columns if x not in ['AEX','DAX','CAC40']]
```

Or if not problem with sorted columns names use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
emerging_names = log_r.columns.difference(['AEX','DAX','CAC40'])
```